# Gridview with dynamic radiobutton list

Tags: gridview

I have created one grid view with radiobuttonlist as shown in figure. radio-button list items are bind dynamically from SharePoint list.

When I click on submit button, unable to get selected radio option. its always give empty value except first option is selected.string value return empty and int I return -1.

[image]

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     SPList oList = Generalfunction.GetList(oWeb, "Question", false);
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='IsActive' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq></Where>";
                dt = oList.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();

  if (dt != null)
            {
                GridQue.DataSource = dt;
                GridQue.DataBind();
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridQue.Rows)
                {
                    RadioButtonList optionlist = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("optionlist");
                    int i = row.RowIndex;
                    string[] Value = dt.Rows[i]["Options"].ToString().Split(new char[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    foreach (string s in Value)
                    {
                        optionlist.Items.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }


protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridQue.Rows)
                    {
                        RadioButtonList optionlist = row.FindControl("optionlist") as RadioButtonList;
 string value = optionlist.SelectedValue;
                int i = optionlist.SelectedItem;
}
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
                Label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }


        }

<asp:GridView ID="GridQue" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%--<asp:Label ID="lblQNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionNo")%>'></asp:Label>--%>
                <asp:Label ID="lblQid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title")%>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question")%>'></asp:Label>

                <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Answer")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="optionlist" runat="server">
                </asp:RadioButtonList>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following

```
 foreach (string s in Value)
                    {
                        optionlist.Items.Add(s.Trim());
                    }
```